# What does "Fama-MacBeth logit regressions" mean?

Tags: logistic, references, econometrics, panel-data, cross-section

On page 10 of [this paper](http://www.chicagobooth.edu/jar/conference/docs/DoMarketsUnder-Kumar.pdf) the author states that

> In this section, I use monthly Fama and MacBeth (1973) logit
>   regression [...]

to examine the type of forecast. My question(s) are:

1. what does this mean,
2. is it even remotely justified by the typical conditions making
   normal [Fama-MacBeth
   procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fama%E2%80%93MacBeth_regression)
   (namely, that asset returns are approximately serially
   uncorrelated), and
3. how does the nonlinearity of error in the coefficient estimate
   affect the aggregation of the cross-sectional estimates?

My take is that

1. it means that he runs a single cross-sectional regression each month
   and forms the point estimates and standard errors from the time
   series of these estimates,
2. probably not exactly, but this is not so important (people use
   Fama-MacBeth in many contexts where the individual estimates are not
   independent), and
3. I have no idea.

Any insight or other interpretations of this would be much appreciated. I would also welcome references to other papers applying a similar methodology ([here is one](http://www.bauer.uh.edu/departments/finance/documents/Religion.pdf)). A fully rigorous argument (or pointer towards one) justifying (or showing it to be incorrect) such a procedure would be optimal.